# SQL to JPA @NamedQuery Conversion

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, java-ee-6

I'm looking for an intelligent way to convert this SQL statement into @NamedQuery --if there is a way at all?

```
SELECT MONTH(dateField), sum(value) FROM mydb.records where status ='paid' group by MONTH(dateField) order by MONTH(dateField);
```

I have a JPA @Entity called Record (Hibernate). This details all invoices in the system  that are created on daily basis. There will be many entries per month. Each record will have a status of paid, overdue, value, and lots of other info such as name and address of customer and so on etc.

The above statement basically summarises all the data on a month by month basis and sums the value of all paid invoices per month giveing a summary of all invoices paid in January, all paid in Feb and so on.....The result looks somethings like:

```
datefield    value
1            4500
2            5500
3            5669
```

The only way I can think of doing this using JPA @NamedQuery is to select all records in the table that are of status 'pai'd and then use my Java code to do the sorting, ordering and addition in a rather slow and ugly fashion! Is there a clever way I can do this with @NamedQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MONTH()` is not a standard JPQL function defined in the JPA spec, however there is an alternative.

Make a view in your database that leverages your databases month function.

```
create view MONTLY_REVENUE as
    SELECT MONTH(dateField), 
       sum(value) 
    FROM mydb.records 
    where status ='paid' 
    group by MONTH(dateField) 
    order by MONTH(dateField);
```

Then just create this entity as you would from any other table with JPA.  You can select from the view but will not be able to save and update it, however since your using the aggregates its not like you would anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Kevin, looks great and much simpler than my Java looping! So this new 'view' will automatically map to a JPA `@`Entity MONTHLY_REVENUE{} that i create? And then a `@`NamedQuery selecting all in new `@`Entity MONTHLY_REVENUE will yield results?

Comment: @user1843591 Exactly.

Comment: Hi Kevin, can I add a 'dynamic' value or dynamic parameter to the view?  e.g. view as u described..xxx where status  ='paid' and where vendorid = ${} .... I simplified my original question a bit too much. Original solution would aggregate all invoices for all vendors. I allow vendors to login and view their data but it is all stored in the one table so i would only want to aggregate on vendor by vendor basis...

Comment: Just add the vendor id as a parameter in the HQL and include it as a where clause.